# Table B Pop-Up Not Updating on or after the 2nd try from Table A

Tags: ms-access, vba

What I am hoping to do is when I open Form A, then click a button to open pop-up window of Form B. The user then select an option in Form B which goes back and updates the textbox field in Form A.

This work on the first record that loads; however, if I try to change to another record on Form A, Form B will not update/populate the information back to Form A. Additional, when looking at Form B's table it shows the original Foreign Key that was loaded and doesn't change/update.

This is what I used to solve a previous the problem; however, that was when I was doing Data Entry and didn't need to change records which this following link worked well.

[VBA access: Refreshing a form from another form's code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6426144/vba-access-refreshing-a-form-from-another-forms-code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moving the first declared SetTempVar of the Foreign Key from the Onload of Form A to the button that goes to Form B allowed Form B to update Form A's Table and Form correctly.